# change value of objects inside array of object with form input with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm new to react and I'm trying to make a workout tracker but I have become hardstuck on trying to capture the input of the exercises the way I'd like, as you can see by the many commented out code blocks I think that I'm missing something fundamental with useState maybe?

this is my useState

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    date: "",
    exercises: [{ Exercise: "benchpress", Reps: "5", Sets: "5" }],
  });
```

this works with the title and date but i've tried many approaches and cant get it work with the object inside the exercise array

this is the onChange function on the form inputs

```
 const updateForm = (e) => {
    setFormData((currentFormData) => ({
      ...currentFormData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
```

All the solutions I've tried has just led to adding whole new objects to the exercises array, or just adding the name + value in the original object next to the title and date.

Comment: post the html input code

Comment: You have a typo, you need to close the benchpress value with "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey try like this it will update your exercise name and you can add more input fields to update more values

```
import * as React from 'react'
const Comp = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    title: '',
    date: '',
    exercises: [{ Exercise: 'benchpress', Reps: '5', Sets: '5' }]
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('gg', formData)
  }, [formData])
  const handle = (e, type) => {
    console.log('gg', e)
    setFormData({
      title: formData.title,
      date: formData.date,
      exercises: [
        {
          Exercise: type === 'E' ? e : formData.exercises[0].Exercise,
          Reps: type === 'R' ? e : formData.exercises[0].Reps,
          Sets: type === 'S' ? e : formData.exercises[0].Sets
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value, 'E')} />

      <input placeholder="rep" onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value, 'R')} />
      <input onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value, 'S')} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Not the best way but it works
For an array with large number of objects/feilds you should use map instead of hard coding them

Comment: I just tried that out and I can see how it changes the exercise value, how can I get that to happen for the reps and sets aswell? I would post my html but it's too long for a comment

Comment: just do the exact thing i did for exercise

Comment: I tried and it just changes the Exercise value

Comment: Check my answer, Its not the best way but it works

Comment: Just tried it out and works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
setFormData(formData.map((line, i) => {
    line.title= "";
    line.date="",
    line.exercises.map((lineExerc, j) => {
        lineExerc.name = e.target.value;
     });
return line;
}));
```